# i have used sql aggregate function and it has returned me some value and i want to perform opertion on that value

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT DISTINCT continent, sum(population) 
over 
(
    PARTITION by continent 
    order by population
    range BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
) as "all_population"
from country
```

I have summed all the population by continent but now i want to sum all of that population record and want a 1 single record how can i do that?

Comment: Adding sample data would be helpful. We have no idea what your data is like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use your query as a subquery like

```
select sum(all_population) 
  from (SELECT DISTINCT continent, 
               sum(population) over ( PARTITION by continent order by population range BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) as "all_population" 
          from country)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want:

```
select sum(population)
from country;
```

As for the query you have written, it is much more commonly written using `group by`:

```
select continent, sum(population)
from country
group by continent;
```

Window functions do not seem appropriate for either of your queries.

If you wanted to add the total population as a new *column* in this query, you would use:

```
select continent, sum(population),
       sum(sum(population)) over () as total_population
from country
group by continent;
```